# Выпадающее меню исчезает при наведении

Tags: html, css

Подкажите как решить проблему...

```css
/*! normalize.css v8.0.0 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
body, html {
    height: 100%
}

   
.wrapper {
    background-color: #dadad5
}

.content {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 300px
}


.header {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto
}

.header-nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center
}

.header-nav__reserve {
    margin-left: auto
}

.header-nav__menu {
    margin: auto
}

.logo {
    margin-right: 40px
}

.logo__img {
    width: 140px;
    height: auto
}

.menu__list {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center
}

.menu__item {
    padding: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu {
    bottom: -60px
}

.menu__item:hover .sub-menu__item {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
}

.menu__link {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent
}

.menu__link:hover {
    color: #d3a352;
    border-top: 1px solid #d3a352;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3a352
}

.lang__list {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center
}

.lang__link {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    color: #000
}

.lang__link:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 1px;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: background-color .5s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color .5s ease;
    transition: background-color .5s ease;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: transparent
}

.lang__link:hover {
    color: #d3a352
}

.lang__link:hover:after {
    background-color: #d3a352
}

.lang__item:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid #000
}

.lang-active {
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #d3a352
}

.reserve__link, .sub-menu {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out
}

.reserve__link {
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: transparent
}

.reserve__link:hover {
    color: #fcfcf6;
    border: 1px solid #d3a352;
    background-color: #d3a352
}

.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15)
}

.sub-menu__list {
    line-height: 60px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center
}

.sub-menu__item, .sub-menu__link {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out
}

.sub-menu__item {
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 0 20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    letter-spacing: 1.2px
}

.sub-menu__link {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff
}

.sub-menu__link:hover {
    color: #d3a352
}
```

```html
<body class="index-page">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header class="header">
        <div class="header-nav">
          <div class="header-nav__logo">
            <div class="logo"><a class="logo__link" href="#"><img class="logo__img" src="static/images/content/logo.png"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="header-nav__lang">
            <div class="lang">
              <div class="lang__list">
                <div class="lang__item"><a class="lang__link lang-active" href="#"> RU</a></div>
                <div class="lang__item"><a class="lang__link" href="#">EN</a></div>
                <div class="lang__item"><a class="lang__link" href="#">CN</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="header-nav__menu">
            <nav class="menu">
              <div class="menu__list">
                <div class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">О нас</a>
                  <div class="sub-menu">
                    <div class="sub-menu__list">
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">О ресторане</a></div>
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">СМИ о нас</a></div>
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">Виртуальный тур</a></div>
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">Отзывы</a></div>
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">Скидочная карта</a></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">События</a>
                  <div class="sub-menu">
                    <div class="sub-menu__list">
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">мероприятия</a></div>
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">спецпредложения</a></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Галерея</a>
                  <div class="sub-menu">
                    <div class="sub-menu__list">
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">интерьер</a></div>
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">блюда</a></div>
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">бар</a></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Меню</a>
                  <div class="sub-menu">
                    <div class="sub-menu__list">
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">европа</a></div>
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">индия</a></div>
                      <div class="sub-menu__item"><a class="sub-menu__link" href="#">бар</a></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Банкеты</a></div>
                <div class="menu__item"><a class="menu__link" href="#">Контакты</a></div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <div class="header-nav__reserve">
            <div class="reserve"><a class="reserve__link" href="#">Зарезервировать</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/evgeny-m/pen/QPrOJR ссылка на код

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/QPrzOb вот так